How do I create a transparent gap effect around a button nested in a React Native tab bar?
The goal is to replicate this image in React Native.

From the user's perspective this center blue plus "tab" button has a transparent gap around it - making it stand out from the other tab options.
But here's the interesting part, this tab or button only appears when the user is in the Today tab.
So I think to myself... is the developer perhaps mutating the tab bar when the user is on Today, and then on the Today Screen itself positioning the button? Or is there a way to accomplish this effect all in the Tab.Group? If so, how does one achieve this effect?
p.s. they are not applying a button border of the same gray color. When content slides down it is visible directly behind the button.
